# Creating check boxes for each markers generated by xml GOOGLE MAPS

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I already have a working map where it generates a valid xml and can generate a marker on my map. Now what I want to do is to upon generating of maps for each loop in the xml I can create asynchronously a check box for each name. here is the code that generates the xml

```
function searchNearLocations(radius){
clearLocations();

 var searchUrl = './designIncludes/phpLogicIncludes/searchMarkers.php?lat=' + userLat +'&lng=' + userLng + '&radius=' + radius;
 downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
   var xml = parseXml(data);
   var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
     var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
     var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
     var info = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("info");
     var tts = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("tts");
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));

     createMarker(latlng, name, address,info,tts);
     createCheckboxes(name);
     bounds.extend(latlng);
   }
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });       
}
```

My createMarker()

```
function createMarker(latlng, name, address,info,tts) {
  var html = "<b>" + name + "</b></br><u>" + address + "</u></br>" + info + "</br>" + "Time allowance to spend: " + tts;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}
```

I'm not that good in javascript but I have a marker=[] array global variable. Can I use that variable to generate a checkbox with it?by the way I also have a pre made marker before invoking the searchNearLocations function and I want to add it on the latlng bounds. Is it possible to insert it on the loop?

Comment: Yes you can; no problem.  Can you show createMarker(), please?  That's where the interesting action is.

Comment: done editing I already added the createMarker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay

Everything not having to do with the checkboxes, I ignored.  You'll have to put it back in your code.
I wrote a functioning example, you can copy/paste this as is.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var markers = [];
var map;

/* I don't have that XML.  I'll just insert a few locations hard coded.  You can ignore this; it doesn't affect your question  */
var markerNodes = [
  {latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(50.896328544032805,4.4825010816688), name: 'Brussels Airport', address: 'A201, 1930 Zaventem', info: 'National airport of Brussels', tts: 'foo'},
  {latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(50.8957080950929,4.334064952575659), name: 'Football stadion', address: 'Marathonlaan', info: 'Football stadion of the Red Devils', tts: 'foo'},
  {latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(50.82302545625156,4.39255052014533), name: 'VUB campus', address: 'Pleinlaan 2', info: 'University of Brussels', tts: 'foo'}
];

function initialize() {
  var position = new google.maps.LatLng(50.84499325563654,4.349978498661017);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: position
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
  searchNearLocations(null);  // I ignore the radius part.  I presume this searches for locations in a DB, or something... 
}

/* never mind most of the changes I made here, it's just to ignore the xml part of the code */
function searchNearLocations(radius) {
  clearLocations();
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i=0; i<markerNodes.length; i++) {
    var latlng = markerNodes[i].latlng,
         name = markerNodes[i].name,
         address =  markerNodes[i].address,
         info = markerNodes[i].info,
         tts = markerNodes[i].tts;
    createMarker(latlng, name, address, info, tts);
    createCheckbox(name, i);  // the most important thing is to pass the i; then markers[i] corresponds with checkboxes[i]
    bounds.extend(latlng);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function createMarker(latlng, name, address, info, tts) {
  // var html = "<b>" + name + "</b></br><u>" + address + "</u></br>" + info + "</br>" + "Time allowance to spend: " + tts;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    title: name,     // You should add this
    position: latlng
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    /* I'll ignore the infoWindow  */
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}
function clearLocations() {
  for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers=[];
}
function checkboxChanged(i, checked) {
  if(checked) {
    markers[i].setMap(map);
  }
  else {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
}
function createCheckbox(name, i) {
  document.getElementById('checkboxes').innerHTML += 
    '<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="checkboxChanged(' + i + ', this.checked);"> ' + name + '<br>';
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<style>
#map-canvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}
</style>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="checkboxes"></div>
```

Can you manage to include this in your code?

---

EDIT:
Here is an example of locations in a DB; I bypass xml and communicate through JSON.
It gives you (kind of) a combination of your questions;
I have a different table on my DB, but that shouldn't be a problem.
I add jQuery, just for ajax.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stations (
  id bigint(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  lat decimal(12,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  lng decimal(12,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  name varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
INSERT INTO stations (id, lat, lng, name) VALUES
(1, '50.8456035000', '4.3568658000', 'Brussel-Centraal'),
(2, '50.8413140000', '4.3490830000', 'Brussel-Kapellekerk'),
(3, '50.8517507000', '4.3623635000', 'Brussel-Congres'),
(4, '50.8604931000', '4.3607035000', 'Brussel-Noord'),
(5, '50.8348278000', '4.3365303000', 'Brussel-Zuid');
```

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var markers = [];
var map;

// settings, to pass to the DB
var lat = 50.84499325563654;
var lng = 4.349978498661017;
var radius = 1.5;  /* set this to more than 1.5 to see more locations */

function initialize() {
  var position = new google.maps.LatLng(50.84499325563654, 4.349978498661017);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: position
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
  searchNearLocations(lat, lng, radius);
}

function searchNearLocations(lat, lng, radius) {
  document.getElementById('checkboxes').innerHTML = '';
  // we start an Ajax call.  
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: {lat: lat, lng: lng, radius: radius},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      // the request has returned data.  Now we can proceed
      clearLocations();
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng),
             name = data[i].name;
             /* add what ever extra data you need */
        createMarker(latlng, name, null, null, null);
        createCheckbox(name, i);  // the most important thing is to pass the i; then markers[i] corresponds with checkboxes[i]
        bounds.extend(latlng);
      }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  });
}

function createMarker(latlng, name, address, info, tts) {
  /* var html = "<b>" + name + "</b></br><u>" + address + "</u></br>" + info + "</br>" + "Time allowance to spend: " + tts;  */
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    title: name,     // You should add this
    position: latlng
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    /* I'll ignore the infoWindow  */
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}
function clearLocations() {
  for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers=[];
}
function checkboxChanged(i, checked) {
  if(checked) {
    markers[i].setMap(map);
  }
  else {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
}
function createCheckbox(name, i) {
  document.getElementById('checkboxes').innerHTML += 
    '<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="checkboxChanged(' + i + ', this.checked);"> ' + name + '<br>';
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<style>
#map-canvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}
</style>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="checkboxes"></div>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'stackoverflow');  /* put your settings back */
if(!$link) {
  die ('unable to connect to the database' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
//Get parameters from URL
$myLat = (isset ($_GET['lat']) ? $_GET['lat'] : 0.0);  // give it some default
$myLng = (isset ($_GET['lng']) ? $_GET['lng'] : 0.0);
$calcDistance = (isset ($_GET['radius']) ? $_GET['radius'] : 1.0);
//Search the rows in the markers table

/* I have a slightly different table; I'll continue with mine; it's easy to put everything back */
// $query = sprintf("SELECT siteName,address,lat,lng,info,tts, (6371 * acos(cos(radians('%s')) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians ('%s')) + sin(radians('%s')) * sin(radians(lat))))AS distance FROM mapTable HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0, 50",
$query = sprintf("SELECT id, lat, lng, name, (6371 * acos(cos(radians('%s')) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians ('%s')) + sin(radians('%s')) * sin(radians(lat)))) AS distance FROM stations HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0, 50",
mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $myLat),
mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $myLng),
mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$myLat),
mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $calcDistance));
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if(!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysqli_error());
}
header("content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
$items = array();
//iterate through the rows,
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $items[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($items);  // this can immediatly be read by javascript
exit;
?>
```

You can add links/buttons, whith something like

```
<div onclick="searchNearLocations(50.80, 4.35, 20)">click: 20 km radius from (50.80, 4.35)</div>
```

To add the position of the client, check out my answer here
[google getLocation function not work in my script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754939/google-getlocation-function-not-work-in-my-script/26757427#26757427)

Comment: many thanks to you sir Emmanuel, you have saved me from my problem. I'll put this on my code when i get home. Again thankyou ver much

Comment: My pleasure.  By the way, just one thought: there is nothing wrong with xml, but for javascript it is easier to read JSON.  It's a string format, just like I show with "var markerNodes = ...".  Javascript sees this as an object, without anything else.  With php you could generate that string. sprintf if perfect for this; there is also the php-function json_encode.  Interested?

Comment: I sure am. Actually I just started studying javascript 1 month ago because I've learned that you cannot do google maps without knowing javascript. I also read about json and it is much more easier to read than xml. I really even wanted to use JSON than xml but since I am still a beginner in java scripting then I guess xml will work for me. Thanks again for the help sir Emmanuel.

Comment: Cool. I understand the JSON code better compared to XML with those nodes nodes etc. thingy. How'd you know that I was using mysqli lol!. by the way can I ask one last question? How can I clear the previous checked boxes? because when i run your code it really worked like magic but when I input another radius which is smaller than the initial the checkboxes still remains while the markers update. And is it possible to include the position variable in the initialize function to the bounds? I'm going to start rewriting my php code and my ajax function code.. So cool. Thanks Sir Emmanuen

Comment: Try the latest update.  I saw your other questions; this is a compilation of most of them.  It's not exactly clear what you're asking about the position in initialize. Try it out, move some parts ...

Comment: I will, Many thanks sir. I'll do the rewriting of my codes right away. Sorry if I'm flooding stack with the same questions, I really need to finish this before the month ends. What I mean is since the latlng bounds is used to automatically adjust the map to make the markers visible to the map is it possible to also include the user's original position to the bounds too? Anyway thank you Sir. I know I've been wasting your time because of this simple problem where I don't even know the answer. Again thank you sir

Comment: Mr. Emmanuel I'm currently having a problem with the checkbox. I didn't use the JSON part because I'm having this too much recursion problems so I stick with the xml, the one you edit first. The problem that I'm having with the checkbox is whenever I try to turn off the checkbox the markers don't turn off and I have this reference error that checkboxChanged is not defined though I already have them on my script. I tried changing the function name but still the error says that the function is not defined. What could seems to be the problem..

Comment: Can you e-mail me emmanueldelay@gmail.com (they don't like ongoing discussions and changeing requirements)